# Using Variables in SSIS for an Excel Destination

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a project where I need to extract data from a SQL Database into 40+ Excel Spreadsheets. What I am trying to do with SSIS is to use variables to set the name of the destination as I move through the workflow. What tips and tricks do people have to do this? If I set the variable value before I run the data flows it works but if I don't set them it fails. I have setup an Expression Task to set the variable in the flow but this doesn't seem to flow through to the SQL Task. Are there any gotcha's with reading and writing to variables?

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: Is the column names different for all the excel sheets and are you extracting from the same table or multiple tables ?

Comment: The column names and number of columns are different in all the spreadsheets. Like the spreadsheets we are extracting different data from the database for each spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve `parallelism` then the best way is to create the variables .Assign the excel sheet names and then execute all your data flow tasks at the same time .

If you are having a hard time to create 40 variables ,then you can go with foreach loop .Select the `foreach loop item enumerato`r .Specify all your file names .Inside the foreach loop drag and drop 40 DFT and based upon the value from foreach loop (using `precedence constraint`) ,particular data flow task will be executed .But this way you will lose  parallelism .